# Why do I get: LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right

Tags: labels, warnings

I try to debug my LaTex File and for that I started with this minimal code example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

%#####################################

\begin{document}

\paragraph{Paragraph:}
\label{par:paragraph}
Test

\end{document}
```

Why do I get the warning here?? I can't figure it out.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Welcome to the site.  To fully resolve labels requires 2 compilations.  If you recompile once more, the warning goes away.  The first compilation collects the `\label` information and writes it to the aux file.  The second compilation will make sure that corresponding `\ref`s, if they exist, point to the proper label.

Comment: Also, the article class, by default, does not count paragraphs, and thus a label is ineffective.  You must increase `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}` for the `\label` to be effective.

Comment: If you are an AUCTeX user, all the necessary compilations are executed automatically without any intervention on your part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I commented there are two issues.  First the warning.  To fully resolve labels requires 2 compilations. If you recompile once more, the warning goes away. The first compilation collects the `\label` information and writes it to the aux file. The second compilation will make sure that corresponding `\ref`s, if they exist, point to the proper label.

Secondly, the issue of paragraphs.  The article class, by default, does not count paragraphs, and thus a label is ineffective. You must increase `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}` for paragraphs to be counted and for the `\label` to be effective.  Otherwise, with a depth of `3`, only `\section`, `\subsection`, and `\subsubsection` get numbers, but not `\paragraph`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

%#####################################
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\begin{document}

About to begin paragraph~\ref{par:paragraph}

\paragraph{Paragraph:}
\label{par:paragraph}
Test

\end{document}
```

After the first compilation, this is the result, because the `\ref` has no `\label` information with which to use.

[image]

The second compilation can use the information written to the aux file to resolve the references, resulting in:

[image]